# Nested loops in R from columns of airplane routes

Tags: r

I am trying to make a double nested loop in R.  The source is stored in `routes` and looks like this:

```
    Airline AirlineID SourceAirport SourceAirportID DestinationAirport DestinationAirportID Codeshare Stops Equipment
```

Where every row is a flight.  I am concerned with the SourceAirportID and the DestinationAirportID.  My double nested loop should have the first index as the SourceAirportID to access a list of DestinationPortIDs.  The nested loop needs to be of variable size because airports will not all have the same number of destinations.  Here is my attempt:

```
graph <- list()
for (i in 1:11922) {
  graph[i] <- list()
}

it <- 1
sid <- as.numeric(routes[1,4])
for (i in 1:length(routes$SourceAirportID)) {
  if (sid != as.numeric((routes[i,4]))) {
    sid <- as.numeric(routes[i,4])
    it <- 1
  }
  else {
    it <- it + 1
  }

  graph[sid][it] <- routes[sid,6]

}
```

Here are the first 4 rows of routes:

```
      Airline AirlineID SourceAirport SourceAirportID DestinationAirport DestinationAirportID Codeshare Stops                           Equipment
17313      CG      1308           GKA               1                HGU                    3               0                             DH8 DHT
17314      CG      1308           GKA               1                LAE                    4               0                                 DH8
17315      CG      1308           GKA               1                MAG                    2               0                                 DH8
17316      CG      1308           GKA               1                POM                    5               0                                 DH8
```

So I'm trying to get the list at `graph[1]` to contain `3 4 2 5`.  Instead graph[1] is null, graph[2] contains 4, graph[3] contains 2 and graph[3] contains 5.  My code also throws over 50 warnings, so clearly I am doing something very wrong.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: For the sake of this SO question, there are a lot of unnecessary elements.  Could you include a representative dataset with more rows (not just for the first airport) and many fewer columns (I think just SourceID and DestinationID are necessary, correct?).  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why graph[2] to graph[4] have only 1 element.  I get that graph[1] has all destinations for SourceAirportID == 1.  Are you trying to use each prior DestinationAirportID as the SourceAirportID for subsequent iterations? I agree with @wibeasley. We need to see a more representative data set. Perhaps a reproducible data.frame with 3 interconnected airports in source and destination columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
#reproduciable data:

    routes <- data.frame(SourceAirport=c('a','a','b','c','a','b','b','c'),
               DestinationAirport=c('Q','W','D','D','Q','E','R','T'))
    View(routes)
    graph <- list()
    o <- unique(routes$SourceAirport)

#DestinationAirports of routes that share the same SourceAirport will be saved within an element in graph

    for (i in 1:length(o)) {
     graph[[i]] <- routes$DestinationAirport[routes$SourceAirport==o[i]]
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!